# Menu is frozen and cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm building a website and I'm using multiple divs to group everythin. But i I add a div on the page my menu is frozen and you cannot click on it anymore. Also the overlay on the menu is not working any more. 
Below is my html code:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>TestManager - Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/createcase.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="dashboard.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="createcase.html">Create Testcase</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="logoff" href="logout.html">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="create">
      <div class="creatcase">
        <h3>Project Overview</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script>
    var userid = sessionStorage.getItem('userid');
    if (userid == null) {
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('test'));
  </script>
```

Below is my css file

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: monospace;
}
ul.menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.menu li{
  float: left;
}
ul.menu li a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li a:hover{
  background-color: #00cc33;
}
ul.menu .active{
  background-color: #00cc33;
}
.create{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.creatcase{
    width: 292px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.creatcase h3{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.creatcase input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
    outline: none;
}
.creatcase select{
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
    outline: none;
}
.creatcase button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #00cc33;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #00e639;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: monospace;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.creatcase button:hover{
    background: #33ff66;
}
```

What am I missing here because I'm stuck on this issue and cannot find the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "create" div is covering the entire screen, preventing mouse events from falling through to the menu.

```
.create{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Position this div below the menu, as shown here:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
}

ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #00cc33;
}

ul.menu .active {
  background-color: #00cc33;
}

.create {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.creatcase {
  width: 292px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.creatcase h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.creatcase input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  outline: none;
}

.creatcase select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  outline: none;
}

.creatcase button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #00cc33;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00e639;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.creatcase button:hover {
  background: #33ff66;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="dashboard.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="createcase.html">Create Testcase</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="logoff" href="logout.html">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="create">
  <div class="creatcase">
    <h3>Project Overview</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

...or better yet do not use absolute positioning at all; it's prone to this sort of error, and is rarely necessary.  In this case, you could get the same general effect by just doing this:

```
.create {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25%; /* <-- adjust to taste */
}
```